# how do i get the value of a parameter in a CATDrawing and edit it

Tags: vba, catia

I want to be able to get the value of the parameter CATDWG_SH_NO. and add the value of Totalsheets1 to it.
So the final strparam1.Value will give me the total of the 2 mentioned before. The code I have right now only updated the parameter value to the totalsheets1 value.
Another issue I faced was that the code will only update the value when the value existed in the parameters multiple value drop-down list, i.e. if the value 10 was not inside the drop-down list, it will fail to update the parameter.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Function SheetNoUpdate(odoc As Document)

Dim parameters1 As Parameters

Set parameters1 = odoc.Parameters

Set strparam1 = parameters1.Item("CATDWG_REV")
strparam1.Value = "A"
Set strparam1 = parameters1.Item("CATDWG_SH_NO.")
strparam1.Value = Totalsheets1.Value

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I interpret you question correct: If you like to add the values try:

```vb
strparam1.Value = strparam1.Value + Totalsheets1.Value
'or if both are strings
strparam1.Value = CStr(CInt(strparam1.Value) + CInt(Totalsheets1.Value))
```

Or do you want to create a formula?
On an multi-value parameter you can get the values (array) with `GetEnumerateValues` and `SetEnumerateValues` to assign an array.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that my strparam1.value was a string.